# Highly confusing express.Router() issue

Tags: express, serverless-framework

I have a large application build with `NestJS` that I deploy using the `serverless framework`. I have been doing this for some time and everything has been great. A couple of days ago I had to update to `Nestjs 7` and I have been experiencing a lot of issues bootstrapping my application when it is deployed to `aws`.  After going through countless frustrating attempts to resolve the issue it appears it's actually nothing to do with the Nestjs/serverless bootstrapping process at all and `apollo-server-express` was unable to access the express router - failing with the error:

`express_1.default.Router is not a function`

Finally I realised that when I import `express` directly and try and access `express.Router()` I have the same issue. So I made a very simple test:

lambda.ts:

```
import { Context, Handler } from "aws-lambda";
import express from "express";

export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  console.log("Import express:", express);
  console.log("Test express app: ", express());
  console.log("Test router:", express.Router());

  /* express.Router() ->
  ERROR TypeError: express_1.default.Router is not a function at 
  /var/task/dist/lambda.js:19:51 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at 
  /var/task/dist/lambda.js:8:71 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at 
  __awaiter (/var/task/dist/lambda.js:4:12) at exports.handler (/var/task/dist/lambda.js:16:39) at 
  Runtime.handler (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:131872) at 
  Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)
  */
};
```

This fails with the error in the comment as previously stated.  Here are the other files:

serverless.yml:

```
service: xxxxx
app: xxxx
tenant: xxxxx

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-deployment-bucket

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-1
  stage: dev
  timeout: 29
  memorySize: 3008
  deploymentBucket:
    name: ${self:service}-${self:custom.currentStage}-deployment-bucket
    serverSideEncryption: AES256

custom: ${file(./serverless-common.yml):custom}
package:
  include:
    - ./dist/**
  exclude:
    - node_modules/aws-sdk/**

functions:
  index:
    handler: ./dist/lambda.handler
    name: bm-${self:custom.currentStage}-express-test
    events:
      - http:
          path: "/{proxy+}"
          method: POST
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@xxx/XXXXXX",
  "version": "0.1.13",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-deployment-bucket": "1.1.1",
    "serverless-prune-plugin": "1.4.2",
    "serverless-pseudo-parameters": "2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.7.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.7.0",
    "tslint": "5.12.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@root/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["*"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**/*", "dist"]
}
```

I would like to highlight that this code only fails once deployed to lambda. It runs fine locally which would make indicate that perhaps something was up with the packaging process but the zip file contains the correct code and dependencies.

I have been working on this problem for ages before narrowing it down to this. If anybody is able to shed any light on the above that would be greatly appreciated as it's obviously blocking me.

Many thanks

---

UPDATE:

OK it appears that if I:

`import Router from 'express/lib/router'`

then I get a router instance. This is the same instance the express index should export.

So I am close but this feels wrong, I haven't changed anything, I feel like I have some kind of incorrect module configuration or something.

So why can't I do `express.Router()`. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

In the end I patched `apollo-server-express` so that it gets the router instance from lib/router and then everything works as expected.

I obviously do not want to do this so I really need to work out what's causing this.

Patched ApolloServer.js: https://gist.github.com/TreeMan360/8dc8373ffebe2b24ff51df42090fcb52

---

UPDATE:

Another related issue has developed in that the headers are returned as part of the response body e.g:

```
HTTP/1.1200OKX-Powered-By: ExpressAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8Content-Length: 155ETag: W/"9b-mbrRmusN4ADjvBFA5aFJNLyRMHs"Date: Sat,
04Apr202014: 35: 09GMTConnection: keep-alive{
  "data": {
    "memberLoginHook": {
      "id": "1bb4ca87-d9f6-4ccb-a2a4-0249b19699b3",
      "occupation": "C3PO",
      "positions": [
        {
          "id": "f4deaf82-ad87-472b-82ab-c78d08138526"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It is also worth noting I have found someone else who has the same issue:
https://forum.serverless.com/t/highly-confusing-express-router-issue/10987/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i’m aware what trigger the issue, very strange bug has very strange solution.
Try lo disable Serverless Framework Enterprise (if it’s enabled), you can just comment the tenant and app rows into your serverless.yml file, and deploy the app again.
I think that there’s a bug in the last version of the serverless-sdk.

Comment: Good deduction, that seems feasible, I didn't even think of that. This indeed fixes the problem in my test lambda.

Untangling myself from enterprise is a pain as I use the secrets manager for stage environment variables.

I have sent a message on the dashboard chat. Let's hope we can get this resolved ASAP. Definitely with a regression test.